# How to call a selector-based Timer method on a Swift struct?

Tags: swift

This is interesting: it appears you can't call a selector message on a swift `struct`! What I mean is this: I've got a `struct` and want to implement a simple `Timer` on it, using the variation of `Timer.scheduledTimer` that takes a `selector:` argument. The compiler tells me that the selector method being called needs an `objc` attribute to make the method visible to an Objective-C calling sequence, but that's not supported (yet another helpful compiler message! ;-) for non-class objects.

I thought using a `struct` was a better way to go in my particular case, but I guess I'm going to have to back-port it to a `class` unless somebody has a better idea...

Comment: Thats really imposible. How would you even pass the struct as a target? It would get copied... Timers are made for reference types. If absolutely required (probably isnt), you can use CFTimer.

Comment: I'm not passing a struct. I'm trying to call a selector-style message @on@ a struct. Sorry if that wasn't clear. (And it might well not be. This was a tricky problem to describe, and I'm not sure my command of technical vocabulary was entirely up to the task. One can only do what one can do, however...)

Comment: That is interesting.

Comment: To call a selector, you need to pass the target. Therefore you would have to pass the struct too. But thats only one if the reasons why this could never work.

Comment: you can use `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:, repeats:,block:)` witch has a block or GCD Timer: `DispatchSource.makeTimerSource ` to avoid use `selector`

Comment: @Sulthan You're right: you are passing the struct (self) as the target. But that doesn't mean it wouldn't work; it would just be inefficient, no? In my case the struct is quite small.

Comment: @Wilson XJ I looked at the variation that uses block: -- that's a nicer api IMHO, but it's limited to iOS 10.0 or later, and I didn't want that restriction.

Comment: @hkatz Nope, it just wouldn't work. It's just impossible to use selectors with value types. Selectors are inherently tied to reference types, or, more specifically, `NSObject` descendants.

Comment: @Sulthan Just reread this thread. You are indeed correct. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but as others have pointed out in the comments this is not possible, directly anyways.

You can achieve creation of Swift `Timer`s within `struct`s by isolating the timer logic into a `class` within the `struct`. The overall plan is as follows.

1. Isolate `Timer` logic into a `class` within the `struct`.
2. Pass the containing `struct` (or some other `class` instance within the `struct`) as a way to communicating back timer ticks.
3. Instantiate the logic `class`, and store a reference to it until needed.

Please see the code example below.

```swift
struct MyStruct{
    
    var timerLogic: TimerLogic!

    class TimerLogic{
        var structRef: MyStruct!
        var timer: Timer!

        init(_ structRef: MyStruct){
            self.structRef = structRef;
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
                timeInterval: 2.0,
                target: self,
                selector: #selector(timerTicked),
                userInfo: nil,
                repeats: true)
        }

        func stopTimer(){
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.structRef = nil
        }

        @objc private func timerTicked(){
            self.structRef.timerTicked()
        }
    }

    func startTimer(){
        self.timerLogic = TimerLogic(self)
    }    

    func timerTicked(){
         print("Timer tick notified")

         // Stop at some point
         // timerLogic.stopTimer()
         // timerLogic = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to follow up, even tho quite a bit of time has passed. that's an interesting answer and has taught me something I didn't know before.

Comment: This is a nice solution, with one exception.  In `func startTimer()`, Xcode squawks about `self.timerLogic`.  This makes it a no-go.

Comment: `mutating func startTimer() {
        self.timerLogic = TimerLogic(self)
    }`   This should help